# Does a spellcaster need to be willing for a Mezlan to use its Store Spells (Su) ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monsters

[Mezlan](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/mezlan/) is a type of morphic ooze with a special ability called Store Spells.

> A mezlan can store up to 10 levels of spells that it can then cast freely. The spells imbued into a mezlan are each activated with the same casting time as the original spell, and are cast at the caster level of the spellcaster who provided the spells. A mezlan can store and use arcane, divine, and psychic spells, and can carry spells from any number of casters at a given time. To fuel this ability, a caster must cast her spells into the mezlan as if storing a spell in an item like a ring of spell storing. The mezlan must be aware of the incoming spell, choose to lower its spell resistance, and ready an action to absorb it. Only spells that have the mezlan as a target can be absorbed in this way; area spells can’t be absorbed. If a mezlan already holds 10 levels of spells, it cannot absorb more spells, and any spell of a level exceeding a mezlan’s available spell level is not absorbed and affects the mezlan normally. Once a spell is absorbed in this manner, the mezlan can use the spell as its own.

I can't tell if both parties must be willing or if the Mezlan could use Spellcraft to identify an incoming spell (after dropping it's SR) and Store it when a spellcaster is unaware of its abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Both blob and caster must be willing

The special ability store spells of a [mezlan](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/mezlan/) says that "a caster must cast her spells into the mezlan as if storing a spell in an item like a [*ring of spell storing*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-spell-storing)." As there's no mention in the *ring*'s description of a creature that's wearing it being able to, for example, ready an action so as to catch in the *ring* an incoming spell, this reader assumes that a mezlan can't do that either.

In other words, enjoy working alongside the spell-storing blob… and feel confident that if you tire of its jibber-jabber it won't be able to store the [*finger of death*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/finger-of-death/) you just used against it and use it against you next turn.